# Problems capturing Python subprocess output on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

I'm running Python 3.3 on Mac OS 10.6.8. I am writing a script that runs several subprocesses, and I want to capture the output of each one and record it in a file. I'm having trouble with this.

I first tried the following:

```
import subprocess
logFile = open("log.txt", 'w')
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=logFile, stderr=logFile)
proc.wait()
```

This produced an empty log.txt. After poking around on the internet for a bit, I tried this instead

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
logFile = open("log.txt", 'w')
logFile.write(output)
```

This, too, produced an empty log.txt. So instead of writing to the file, I tried to just print the output to the command line:

```
output, err = proc.communicate()
print(output)
print(err)
```

That produced this:

```
b''
b''
```

The process I'm trying to run is fastq_quality_trimmer. It takes an input file, filters it, and saves the result to a new file. It only writes a few lines to stdout, like so

```
Minimum Quality Threshold: 20
Minimum Length: 20
Input: 750000 reads.
Output: 750000 reads.
discarded 0 (0%) too-short reads.
```

If I run it from the command line and redirect the output like this

```
fastq_quality_trimmer -Q 33 -v -t 50 -l 20 -i in.fq -o in_trimmed.fq > log.txt
```

the output is successfully written to log.txt.

I thought perhaps that fastq_quality_trimmer was somehow failing to run when I called it with Popen, but my script produces a filtered file that is identical to the one produced when I run fastq_quality_trimmer from the command line. So it's *working*; I just can't capture the output. To make matters more confusing, I *can* successfully capture the output of other processes (echo, other Python scripts) using code that is essentially identical to what I've posted.

Any thoughts? Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: What is `args`?  Is it a string or a `list`?

Comment: To test @MartijnPieters hypothesis, you could substitute your command for something simpler ... say ... `echo foo`.  If you get something from that, then `fastq_quality_trimmer` is doing something funky.

Comment: @mgilson: `args` is a `list`. If I substitute `echo foo` or something similar, it works.

Comment: Here is `args`: `["fastq_quality_trimmer", 
                                    "-Q", "33" 
                                    "-v", 
                                    "-t", "50", 
                                    "-l", "20", 
                                    "-i", leftInitial, 
                                    "-o", leftTrimmed]` `leftInitial` and `leftTrimmed` are filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma:

```
["fastq_quality_trimmer", "-Q", "33" "-v", "-t", "50", "-l", "20", "-i", leftInitial, "-o", leftTrimmed]
```

add it between `"33"` and `"-v"`.

You are essentially passing in the arguments `-Q 33-v` instead of `-Q 33 -v`.

Python will concatenate two adjacent strings if there is only whitespace between them:

```
>>> "33", "-v"
('33', '-v')
>>> "33" "-v"
'33-v'
```

Since `-v` is the verbose switch that is required to make `fastq_quality_trimmer` produce output at all, it'll remain silent with it missing.

Whenever you encounter problems with calling a subprocess, *triple* check the command line created. Pre-pending `args` with `['echo']` can help in that:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo'] + args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
print(output)
```

Comment: Elaborating, the "-v" gets omitted, so fastq_quality_trimmer does not run in verbose mode.

Comment: @user1970411: Yup, had understood that from my check of the utility source already. :-)