# subprocess.Popen('docker', stdout=subprocess.PIPE) does not redirect result only in OSX & only for 'docker'

Tags: python, macos, docker, subprocess

When I run `proc = subprocess.Popen('docker', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` on OSX 10.14.6 (18G84) with Python 3.7.4(installed via Homebrew) and docker 18.09.2(build 6247962), the stdout is printed in the console instead of being redirected.(i.e. `proc.stdout.readlines() == []`)

This only happens to `'docker'` - another subprocess, for example `'ls'`, returned something via `proc.stdout.readlines()` instead of printing its output on the console.

Also, I made sure this is OSX-specific problem by running the same command on the EC2 instance(Amazon AMI 2, Docker 18.06.1-ce, Python 2.7.16&3.7.3), and `proc.stdout.readlines()` of docker subprocess returned the expeced result(no output in console, `proc.stdout.readlines()` contains docker output).

I googled and found a SO post [Problems capturing Python subprocess output on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14282095/9534591) but it seems like it's python problem(typo in python), not OSX problem.

Why is proc.stdout.readlines() returning nothing for 'docker'?

---

More details:

I was using [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) open source cli tool, and one of its command was not working (specifically fixing docker typo commands.)

So I decided to fix it myself, and debugging it led me to [this code](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/blob/master/thefuck/rules/docker_not_command.py#L15):

```py
...
import subprocess
...

def get_docker_commands():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('docker', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in proc.stdout.readlines()]
```

These lines, where docker is run as subprocess and then its stdout is read by `proc.stdout.readlines()` was the source of the problem.

So I tried similar command in the python interactive console and it was like this:

(on Mac OS)

```py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('docker', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(docker help output in console)
>>> proc.stdout.readlines()
[]

>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.stdout.readlines()
(ls of directory '/' as python list)
```

(On EC2 Instance)

```py
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun 24 2019, 19:20:54) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('docker', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.stdout.readlines()
(docker output as python list)
```

I did not include the result but the python2's results are the same. (both Mac&EC2 are Python 2.7.16)

Comment: @Ry- Thank you, I tested it via `docker &> a.out` and it seems like you're correct. I never expected a plain command to output as stderr...

Comment: It’s help output for the invalid command `docker`, so it’s typical for it to be on stderr. `docker --help` produces the same output on stdout.